# How to convert string to integer in Bash?

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell

I have found many answers about this on StackOverflow but I can't apply them to my code.

I used this command to get last day of current month:

```
LASTDAY=`cal $(date +"%m %Y") | grep . | fmt -1 | tail -1`
```

then I use this code:

```
for i in {1..${LASTDAY}}
do
    # code for processing here!
done
```

But always get this warning: 
**line 12: [: {1..31}: integer expression expected**

and **i** is **{1..31}** but I expected **i** is a number in range [1,31]

I have tried this:

```
LASTDAY=$((LASTDAY+0))

LASTDAY=$( echo "$LASTDAY - 0" | bc )

LASTDAY=$(printf "%d" "$LASTDAY")
```

but it can't solve this problem. What's wrong in my code? and how to fix it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm not a `bash` head, but I think the range expression like `{1..31}` maybe a new feature to bash. What version are you using? `bash --version`, should output your version. Add that bit of information to your question above. Good luck.

Comment: You are right. However, I have run this expression many times but it is failed in the case I asked above. FYI, my bash version is: 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Brace expansion has been in `bash` for a long time. However, it occurs prior to parameter expansion; since the braces do not contain two integer literals, the expression is treated literally as the string `{1..${LASTDAY}}`. Then parameter expansion is applied to produce `{1..31}`. That string is rejected by the code that receives `$i`, since that string is not an integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following instead of `for i in {1..$Lastday}`

```
for i in $(seq 1 ${LASTDAY}) ; do  echo $i done
```

This will work.

Comment: Be careful about range length - some shells have limit on 64 KiB line length. In bash use may use usual **for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done**